# UIScrollView constraint issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm working on a `ViewController` with Xib. inside my Xib I have a `UIScrollView` and a `UIView` (content view).

Inside the **Content View** I have another view.

Until now it has always worked, but now my console tells me of the wrong constraints you can tell me where I'm wrong ... until now it never happened.

The constraints I entered are:

- scrollview **top**, **leading**, **bottom**, **trailing** at 0 points
- contentView (inside the scrollView) **top scrollview**, **leading scrollview**, **trailing scrollview**, **bottom scrollview** at 0 points + **equalHeight scrollview** (**priority low 230**) and **equalWidth scrollview**.
- the view in the contentView has **top contentView**, **leading contentView**, **trailing contentView** and (**height 128**)

[image]

Why does the console tell me errors?

[image]

Comment: set scrollView width and height equal to superview, centerX, centerY to superview

Comment: for contentView constraint ???

Comment: for scrollView, I wrote it above

Comment: @kAiN - How are you displaying this? Are you navigating to this view controller? Are you loading it as a child VC and adding its view as a subview?

Comment: @DonMag yes the ViewController is inside a ContainerView like addChildViewController ..
Besides this viewController I also have two other View Controllers but they didn't give me this problem .. why?

Comment: @kAiN - how are you loading the xib-associated view controller as a child VC, and adding its view? Are you adding constraints? Or are you setting its frame?

Comment: yes in fact I had the layout of the container view wrong ... for this reason I was reporting incorrect constraints! thank you @DonMag I was lost in the code and thanks to your suggestion I found the error!